# Android: Get Item from the navigation list actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have used **actionbarsherlock** library, in that i have used `NavigationList` and binded following data:

### get Item from the navigation list:

```
Cursor cCategory = dbh.getCategory();

final String [] cName = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_NAME};
int to[] = new int[]{R.id.listTextView};
Log.d("TAG", "CATEGORY NAME : "+cName.length);

//SIMPLE CURSOR ADAPTER
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
SimpleCursorAdapter categoryAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.textview_for_listview,cCategory, cName, to);
Log.d("TAG", "SIMPLE CURSOR ADAPTER  FOR CATEGORY : "+categoryAdapter.getCount());

// Hide the ActionBar Title
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
// Create the Navigation List in your ActionBar.
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);      

/* Defining Navigation listener */
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NAVIGATION CLICK :", 10).show();

        return false;
    }
};

/* Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
getSherlockActivity().getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(categoryAdapter,navigationListener);
```

I want to get `Item` which is currently selected from `Navigation List` when i clicked on particular item `onNavigationItemSelected`?

Comment: You should specify a little more what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get item from your adapter as said by [flx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2331953/flx) in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21719112/1318946) but it will return Cursor.

so Your `Listener` like this:

```
ab.setListNavigationCallbacks(cityAdapter, new OnNavigationListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor temp = (Cursor) categoryAdapter.getItem(itemPosition);

        Toast.makeText(context, temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndex("your_column_name")), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the selected item from the adapter:

```
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener =new OnNavigationListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(). "selected item: " +
            categoryAdapter.getItem(itemPosition), 10).show();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Don't forget to mark the adapter as `final`. Otherwise you won't be able to access it from inside of the listener.

Comment: It'll suggest automatically to make `final`

Comment: `adapter` returns `Cursor`, It will `Toasting` Cursor's id.

Comment: Sure it does. It's a `CursorAdapter`... You can fetch items from the `Cursor` quite easily.